# How to extract a pattern from string containing binary data

Tags: arrays, ruby, ascii, extract

I have this array that comes from a previous `a=array.unpack("C*")` command.

```
a = [9, 32, 50, 53, 56, 53, 57, 9, 73, 78, 70, 79, 9, 73, 78, 70, 79, 53, 9, 
     32, 55, 52, 32, 50, 51, 32, 48, 51, 32, 57, 50, 32, 48, 48, 32, 48, 48, 32, 
     48, 48, 32, 69, 67, 32, 48, 50, 32, 49, 48, 32, 48, 48, 32, 69, 50, 32, 48, 
     48, 32, 55, 55, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, 57, 254, 70, 6, 1, 6, 0, 3, 
     0, 3, 198, 0, 2, 198, 31, 147, 23, 0, 226, 7, 12, 17, 18, 56, 55, 3, 101, 1, 
     1, 0, 134, 7, 145, 5, 148, 37, 150, 133, 241, 135, 5, 22, 109, 145, 53, 38, 
     171, 4, 3, 2, 6, 192, 173, 22, 160, 20, 48, 18, 6, 9, 42, 134, 58, 0, 137, 97, 
     58, 1, 0, 164, 5, 48, 3, 129, 1, 7, 225, 16, 2, 1, 1, 4, 11, 9, 1, 10, 10, 6, 
     2, 19, 105, 145, 103, 116, 226, 35, 48, 3, 194, 1, 242, 48, 3, 194, 1, 241, 48, 
     3, 194, 1, 246, 48, 3, 194, 1, 245, 48, 3, 194, 1, 244, 48, 3, 194, 1, 243, 48, 
     3, 194, 1, 247, 177, 13, 10, 1, 1, 4, 8, 10, 6, 2, 19, 105, 145, 103, 116, 0, 0, 
     42, 3, 0, 0, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 50, 9, 82, 101, 99, 101, 105, 118, 101, 
     9, 50, 51, 9, 77, 111, 110, 32, 32]
```

when I convert to chr it looks like this:

```
 irb(main):4392:0> a.map(&:chr).join
 => "\t 25859\tINFO\tINFO5\t 74 23 03 92 00 00 00 EC 02 10 00 E2 00 77\t\x00\x00\x00\x00
 \x01\f\x01\x00\x00\x009\xFEF\x06\x01\x06\x00\x03\x00\x03\xC6\x00\x02\xC6\x1F\x93\x17\x00
 \xE2\a\f\x11\x1287\x03e\x01\x01\x00\x86\a\x91\x05\x94%\x96\x85\xF1\x87\x05\x16m\x915&\xAB
 \x04\x03\x02\x06\xC0\xAD\x16\xA0\x140\x12\x06\t*\x86:\x00\x89a:\x01\x00\xA4\x050\x03\x81
 \x01\a\xE1\x10\x02\x01\x01\x04\v\t\x01\n\n\x06\x02\x13i\x91gt\xE2#0\x03\xC2\x01\xF20\x03
 \xC2\x01\xF10\x03\xC2\x01\xF60\x03\xC2\x01\xF50\x03\xC2\x01\xF40\x03\xC2\x01\xF30\x03\xC2
 \x01\xF7\xB1\r\n\x01\x01\x04\b\n\x06\x02\x13i\x91gt\x00\x00*\x03\x00\x000000..."
```

I would like to extract the hexadecimal values between `INFO5\t` and `\t...,` so the output would be

```
 "74 23 03 92 00 00 00 EC 02 10 00 E2 00 77"
```

I'm doing like below but only removes the first unwanted part and leaves `\n\n\x06...000`

How can I fix this?

```
irb(main)>: a.map(&:chr).join.gsub(/(\t .*\t )|(\t.*)/,"")
=> "74 23 03 92 00 00 00 EC 02 10 00 E2 00 77\n\n\x06\x02\x13i\x91gt\xE2#0
\x03\xC2\x01\xF20\x03\xC2\x01\xF10\x03\xC2\x01\xF60\x03\xC2\x01\xF50\x03\xC2
\x01\xF40\x03\xC2\x01\xF30\x03\xC2\x01\xF7\xB1\r\n\x01\x01\x04\b\n\x06\x02\
x13i\x91gt\x00\x00*\x03\x00\x0000000002"
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

**UDPATE**

Below attached sample binary file.

[input.dat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ei5lv3yycv00zfj/input.dat?raw=1)

Comment: I suggest editing the title to be "How to extract a pattern from string containing binary data" (no need to mention "ruby" because it's already a tag)

Comment: Done! Thanks so much for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean `a=str.unpack("C*")` - you can `unpack` a string but not an array.

To get the result you want, you *don't* need to use `unpack` at all<sup>1</sup> - just perform a regex:

```
str.match(/INFO5\t(.*?)\t/).to_a[1]
# => " 74 23 03 92 00 00 00 EC 02 10 00 E2 00 77"
```

Note that there's a leading space in the result, but you can adjust the regex according to your needs; I'm not going to try to guess the specification of this format.

Tips:

- The `?` in `.*?` is needed to make the `*` non-greedy.
- The `to_a` avoids `raise`ing an error in case the `match` finds nothing.

---

**EDIT**

Your comment regarding "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" indicates that your data is probably ASCII-8BIT (i.e. it's not compatible with UTF-8), but it's stored in a string whose encoding attribute is "UTF-8". It would help if you explain how you obtained that string, because the string's encoding appears to be wrong.

**Solution 1** (this is ideal):

Read in the file as ASCII-8BIT:

```
str = File.read("input.dat", encoding: 'ASCII-8BIT')
```

**Solution 2** (a workaround, if you can't control the input encoding):

```
# NOTE: this changes the encoding on `str`
str.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")
```

After you've done this, the `.match` should work.

**Further Explanation**

The reason your `map(&:chr).join` works is because `.chr` will produce either `US-ASCII` or `ASCII-8BIT` strings (the latter happens for bytes above 127), never `UTF-8`.

When you `join` those strings, your result is in `ASCII-8BIT` if any byte was above 127. So this is effectively the same as calling `force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")`, except that `map`/`join` doesn't modify the original string's encoding like `force_encoding` does.

---

<sup>1</sup>`unpack` is unnecessary because `a.map(&:chr).join` is the same as `arr.pack('C*')` which gives you the original `str`. Even if you had to `unpack` the string for another purpose, I recommend using the original string instead of re-`pack`ing the array. Maybe you can encapsulate this into a data structure, e.g.:

```
i_data = InfoData.new(str)
i_data.bytes  # array of bytes
i_data.hex_string  # "74 23 03 ..."
```

Note that the above code won't work as-is - you need to write the `InfoData` class yourself.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, Thanks for your answer. When I try `str.match(/INFO5\t(.*?)\t/).to_a[1]` I get `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
        from (irb):4463:in `match'
        from (irb):4463:in `match'
        from (irb):4463:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):4454:in `foreach'
        from (irb):4454
`

Comment: When I try `InfoData.new(str)` I get this error `i_data = InfoData.new(str)
NameError: uninitialized constant InfoData
`

Comment: It seems that even `a.map(&:chr).join` = `arr.pack('C*')` = Original string, If I first don't do `a=string.unpack("C*")` your code doesn't work and I recieve `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 from`

Comment: Hi Kelvin. In my real file I read it using as line separator a byte sequence like this: `File.foreach("input.dat", sep="\x10\x12", encoding: 'ASCII-8BIT') do |line| next unless line =~ /INFO5/ p line.match(/INFO5\t ?([^\t]*)\t/)[1] end`  so now with your explanation and solution 1 and 2 about ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 I added `encoding: ASCII-8BIT` to the `foreach` like this `File.foreach("input.dat", sep="\x10\x12",  encoding: 'ASCII-8BIT')` and now it works pretty fine. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: One more question, to read this kind of file for which I use as separator a byte sequence is good to use `File.foreach()` or is there a better method?

Comment: @GerCas Glad it helped. For the `foreach` question, please try searching this site or Google and asking it as a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches (`a` below is abbreviated from that given in the question).

```
a = [9, 32, 50, 53, 56, 53, 57, 9, 73, 78, 70, 79, 9, 73, 78, 70, 79, 53, 9, 
     32, 55, 52, 32, 50, 51, 32, 48, 51, 32, 57, 50, 32, 48, 48, 32, 48, 48,
     32, 48, 48, 32, 69, 67, 32, 48, 50, 32, 49, 48, 32, 48, 48, 32, 69, 50,
     32, 48, 48, 32, 55, 55, 9, 0, 0]
```

**Extract from the string that had been unpacked to create `a`**

```
str = a.pack("C*")
  #=> "\t 25859\tINFO\tINFO5\t 74 23 03 92 00 00 00 EC 02 10 00 E2 00 77\t\x00\x00"

str[/(?<=INFO5\t).+?(?=\t)/].strip
  #=> "74 23 03 92 00 00 00 EC 02 10 00 E2 00 77"
```

`str` is the string that had been converted to `a` (`a = str.unpack("C*)`), so it need not be computed.

`(?<=INFO5\t )` and `(?=\t)` are respectively a *positive lookbehind* and a *positive lookahead*. They must be matched but are not part of the match that is returned. The ("non-greedy") question mark in `.+?` ensures that the match terminates immediately before the first tab is encountered. By contrast,

```
"abc\td\tef"[/(?<=a).+(?=\t)/]
  #=> "bc\td"
```

**Extract from `a` and convert to a string**

```
pfix = "INFO5\t".unpack("C*")
  #=> [73, 78, 70, 79, 53, 9]
pfix_size = pfix.size
  #=> 6 
sfix = [prefix.last]
  #=> [9]
sfix_size = sfix.size
start = idx_start(a, pfix) + pfix_size
  #=> 19
a[start..idx_start(a[start..-1], sfix) + start - 1].pack("C*").strip
  #=> "74 23 03 92 00 00 00 EC 02 10 00 E2 00 77"

def idx_start(a, arr)
  arr_size = arr.size
  a.each_index.find { |i| a[i, arr_size] == arr }
end
```

Comment: Hi Cary. Thanks for answer. When I try your solution I get `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
`

Comment: Hi Cary. Please see my update. I've attached a sample file containing the hex string. For me the errors happen only working with the binary file, but your solutions work if I apply them to a text string.

Comment: Thanks so much your updated solutions. You give me more ideas to apply in my code.

Answer (score 1):

1. I assume that you don't need the non-ascii bytes, so in first step I trim them to the first null byte using `take_while`
2. Then I convert ints to string using `map(&:chr).join`
3. Finally I `match` them using a regex that `/INFO5\t ?([^\t]*)\t/` that assumes the interesting part is between `INFO5\t` and next `\t`

--

```
a=array.unpack("C*")
a.take_while{|e| e > 0}.map(&:chr).join.match(/INFO5\t ?([^\t]*)\t/)[1]
# => "74 23 03 92 00 00 00 EC 02 10 00 E2 00 77"
```

Comment: Hi mrzasa, thanks for your help. It work only if I first do `a=hexstring.unpack("C*")` and then apply your code. If I try to apply the code to hexstring directly I get error `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` This is do this `hexstring.match(/INFO5\t ?([^\t]*)\t/)[1]`

Comment: Please, see the edit. I used `a` array you had in the question

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that `hextring` looks the same as `a.map(&:chr).join` but doesn't work if I apply directly to hexstring. I tried that in order to know if I'm doing extra steps, but it seems I need to do first `a=hextring.unpack("C*")` and then apply your code in order to work.